# How to tell R the meaning of a numerical variable and plot them?

Tags: r

I have a large data set in R which I am currently analysing. I'm trying to plot confounding variables and have one which considers the patients household equipment (2=none, 1= stove, 3= charcoal).

How would I tell R to make a graph which considers each of these categories, so I want to correlate malaria ("Malaria...giemsa") against each of the household equipment.

I basically want to see if there are higher counts for malaria if the patient has no household equipment, than if they had a stove/ charcoal etc.

Any suggestions on how to code this into R?

Comment: If you have a question about what would be a suitable graphical display that should be on  topic.

Comment: Your use of  the term 'correlate' is confusing with these type of variables. What type of correlation did you think of? What type of variable is Malaria? Do you basically have only 8 values (counts of yes/no malaria for 4 possibilities of household equipment)?  Then use a table instead of a graph.

Comment: You do this by creating a ```factor``` variable.  Look this up and you will find plenty of web pages explaining how to create and use factors.